# Does General Relativity imply greater accelerations than Newtonian gravity in strong gravitational fields?

Tags: general-relativity, newtonian-gravity, acceleration

Does General Relativity imply greater accelerations than Newtonian gravity in strong gravitational fields, such as at 2 m/s^2?

Do the general relativistic corrections add up to more "gravity" in strong gravitational fields?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the weight equation through general relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47379/)

Comment: Yes they do; there is an "extra" inverse cubic term in the effective potential which overcomes the inverse square "centrifugal repulsion" at very close distances, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem_in_general_relativity#Effective_radial_potential_energy

Answer (score 2):

Yes, instead of the Newtonian $\rm F=m \ a=G \ M \ m/r^2$, under Schwarzschild we have $\rm F=m \ a=G \ M \ m/r^2/\sqrt{1-r_s/r} \ $ for a stationary observer, and at $\rm r=1.5 \ r_s \ $ you'd need $\rm v=1 \ c \ $ in order to orbit, while under Newton you'd need only $\rm 0.577 \ c$, see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/742431/24093).

Comment: Only if you identify r in Newton with r in Schwarzschild!

Comment: @m4r35n357 - Sure, it's the circumference divided by 2π as per the usual convention.

Comment: It is an identification, but it is clearly not the _same thing_.  Anyway, I have done this myself in order to "compare" orbits in Newton with GR, so I am pragmatic about it, I just don't take it seriously as the "same thing".